# Advanced sorting mysql, sort on action id

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

[image]

I need to sort this table on the actionName (it is fetched from an action table and also contains an id). However some players might not have any records for the specific actionName as seen in this screenshot

[image]

I have already accomplished to get it to show the first result, however i have no clue on how i could make it sort for example, per kill or win, it should always group the usernames because i need the resultset to display in a table but then the player with the highest kills on top. I do need to show the other corresponding tables as well without having to execute a lot of queries.

This is the sql i use to accomplish the first resultset

```
SELECT
  p.playerName,
    a.actionName,
  a.id as actionId,
    SUM(a.id) AS amount,
    pa.timestamp
FROM playeraction pa
LEFT JOIN action a ON a.id = pa.action_id
INNER JOIN player p
  ON p.id = pa.player_id
GROUP BY
  pa.player_id,
    pa.action_id
ORDER BY
  p.playerName,
  amount DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a view that would Group by player name, and then in separate columns of that record count the kill, win and death count respectively. That way you would have specific columns for each action, and it wouldn't bother you if user had an action like that or not. The column value would just be 0, since no records were found to sum. This will also resolve the ordering issue, since you would be able to order by each column:

```
ORDER BY KillCount, WinCount, DeathCount
```

In this case though you would have to modify the view if you'd create new actions.

Also, why are you summing a.Id? Didn't you mean count?

EDIT: also you could select from Action table, then join PlayerAction table, that way for each action you would have a record for the action. Something like:

```
SELECT 
a.Id, a.ActionName,
p.Name,
pa.Amount, pa.TimeStamp
FROM Actions a
LEFT JOIN Players p on 1 = 1
LEFT JOIN PlayerActions pa on pa.ActionId = a.Id
GROUP BY
...
ORDER BY
...
```

Only then you'd need to filter the players out by some sort of game match ID.

And then there's an option of just counting the actual results in your application upon receiving the query results. That would also work for your query.

Comment: Yes you are correct, it can be COUNT(a.id), for the columns, i tried to shift the action row names to columns but i dont know how to do that and mysql doesnt support pivot queries, i would also like it to be dynamic so i can add more actions in the future without modifying the code

Comment: But the players won't be bundled together anymore ?

Comment: What do you mean by bundled together?